# Projectile alternative optimized for TRAMP?

Tags: tramp, projectile

I really enjoy Projectile but it continuously doesn't play nice with TRAMP. I was wondering if there were any Projectile alternatives out there. I tried searching the internet but all I get all Projectile tech blog posts and alternatives to SEO hack sites.

Comment: There is the built-in `project` package.  I have no idea if it plays better with `tramp` though.

Comment: Hmm, I don't remember that the projectile author has contacted Tramp development (but I might be wrong). Perhaps she/he tries? FTR, I'm the Tramp maintainer.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus I swear I saw a GitHub issue where some maintainer was expressing frustration about trying to make the project compatible with TRAMP. Removed that part from the question though since it isn't relevant.

Comment: I have no problem with anybody who has frustration with Tramp. I just want to be involved, in order to make packages useful.